# Alternative to application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual for speeding up mailmerge vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

When my code runs and reaches the line `application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual`, there is a compile error saying method or data member not found

---

I have a vba macro which looks inside an excel sheet of values and pulls this data to populate mail merge fields in a word doc.

The macro is executed from a command button click. 
I needed help to speed up the code which is taking over 15 seconds to run.

I added few lines to speed up the code (see below) but when it reaches `application.calculation = xlcalculationmanual` there is a compile error: method or data member not found

I looked this up and someone mentioned using early binding. So I went to tools references and ticked the box for ms excel 16.0 library. The issue with `calculationmanual` remained.

Strangely running the code manually rather than through the command button is much faster. Is there an alternative method of speeding up my mail merge 
code without calculation manual or is it an issue with command buttons?

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'speed up of code    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False    
Activesheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False    
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual    
Application.EnableEvents = False    
'end of speed up of code

  Dim numRecord As Integer
  Dim myDCR As String

myDCR = InputBox("Enter DCR:")    
Set dsMain = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource

With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
 .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
End With

If dsMain.FindRecord(FindText:=myDCR, Field:="DCR") = True Then
    numRecord = dsMain.ActiveRecord
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True    
Activesheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True    
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

---

I expect the code to run and pull the data from excel and populate the word doc in less than 3 seconds.

Comment: Where is your macro?  If it is in Word, and if you have not set your options to require variable declaration, then that message is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I've just ticked to allow variable declaration and the same error comes up. I honestly think this Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual    command may not be useful for speeding up my code. There could be alternatives but I have no idea what these are.

Comment: If all you do is "tick" the option, that only affects new modules.  For existing modules, you need to **place `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.**  and please answer my first question.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ron. The macro is run from msword but the mailmerge data source is excel. It pulls data from Excel to fill ms word fields. Following your advice to include option explicit as an additional line above all of my code still gives the same compile error of CalculationManual. In your experience what commands do you normally use to speed up any code you write?

Comment: To speed up your macro, you need to optimize your algorithm for the environment. The method you are using can help speed up operations in Excel, but are not appropriate for Word (and there are frequently better ways even for Excel). I'm not as familiar with Word, but I'd suggest something along the lines of @macropod's answer, where your code still prompts for user input, but use that input to set up a mailmerge filter (or a `SKIPIF` field in Word.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, since you're doing a mailmerge, your application is Word - for which there is no such thing as Application.Calculation. That's an Excel command and you're not running Excel. Furthermore, if all you're trying to do is limit the merge to a particular set of records, there's no need at all for any VBA. You can use the mailmerge filters or a SKIPIF field coded along the lines of:

```
{SKIPIF {MERGEFIELD DCR}<> {FILLIN "Enter DCR:" \o}}
```

where the field braces (i.e. {}) are created as pairs in the mailmerge main document via Ctrl-F9.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The purpose of the VBA is to prompt the user to enter a number so the macro will fill in several fields pulled from a particular set of records. Therefore the fields will change depending on the number the user has input. Therefore i couldn't limit the fields to just DCR in the above example; there's 10 other fields pulled from 10 columns of data records in the excel sheet.

Comment: As indicated in my previous reply there is *no need for VBA*. You might at least try the SKIPIF field... If you want to filter by multiple criteria, you can have separate SKIPIF fields for each.

Answer (score 1):

You also have no error handling in your code.  If your code breaks after you started making all the Application settings changes, there's nothing to restore those settings back to what they should be.  This can leave your application in a VERY bad state.  Here's what you should be doing:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    'speed up of code    
    On Error GoTo ExitErr
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
       Application.DisplayStatusBar = False    
       Activesheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False    
       Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual    
       Application.EnableEvents = False    
    'end of speed up of code

   Dim numRecord As Integer
   Dim myDCR As String

       myDCR = InputBox("Enter DCR:")    
       Set dsMain = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource

       With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdFirstRecord
       End With

       If dsMain.FindRecord(FindText:=myDCR, Field:="DCR") = True Then
           numRecord = dsMain.ActiveRecord
       End If

    ExitErr:
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
       Application.DisplayStatusBar = True    
       Activesheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True    
       Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic    
       Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks answering but this doesn't resolve the problem pointed out in the post. The  compile error for calculationmanual still remains. If i were to go ahead and remove calculation.manual the macro will still run slow so i need an alternative way of speeding up my code.

Comment: As macropod said, the compile error is caused by calling an Excel explicit function on a Word application.  You need to get the Excel Application as an object in your code and then make the settings changes to that object.  I've never mucked around with calling a different Application using VBA, but you should be able to find something out there about "Calling Excel from a macro in Word".

Comment: Thanks Frank this may be the crux of the matter. I'll have to read up and learn how to call excel from word. Though cutting the amount of data to sift through has given me the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers in the midst of learning about SKIPIF to implement macropod's answer I came up with a very simple intuitive solution.

**Solution**:
Archiving half of the spreadsheet so the spreadsheet now has half the amount of rows it contained before. The spreadsheet contained data from 2016-19 but there was no need to have data before 2019 at hand.

**The reason I think this worked out**:
Rather than speeding up my macro by adding more code I instead cut the amount of data excel has to sift through.

Same result but different way of getting around it. Now the macro runs pretty fast from the command button.